React Native: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
I have been seeing a lot of similar issues but they all seem to be flutter apps. Mine is a React Native app and the solutions I've tried from other threads haven't been working.
As in the title, here's the error I get when I try to do a gradle build:
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Here's where I get the kotlin version in my android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '31.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '33')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '33')
         if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
             kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
         }
        frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == 'aarch64') {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = '24.0.8215888'
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = '21.4.7075529'
        }
    }

As you can see, it's using androidVersion which I think is pulling from whatever version I have in Android studio. So I've been going to Settings-> Other Settings -> Kotlin Compiler and switching between versions 1.6.0 and 1.8.0. I have also tried 1.9.0. No dice - I still see the same error.
I'm still on Gradle version 7.3.3, but I recently updated the target API for my project which is when I started seeing this error.
Any suggestions are appreciated and let me know if I need to provide more information.
Thanks!!
